# How to export sheet/column in VBA to XML in UTF-8 formatting

Tags: excel, xml, vba, utf-8

I have written a macro that outputs xml-lines (with the right formatting) in column A of a certain sheet. So each row in that sheet should correspond to 1 line in an xml-file. If I copy-paste this column in notepad en save it as .xml (after removing the "-tags that are automatically placed before and after each line), I have the file that I need. The macro should generate several files so it is not pratically to do this manually for each file.

I have found following code to do the save-job :

```
strFileName = Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\" & NameOfTheFile & ".xml"
Sheets(NameOfSheetContainingData).SaveAs Filename:=strFileName, FileFormat:=xlTextPrinter, CreateBackup:=False
```

This works perfectly, except for the UTF-8 formatting. Where I have a 'é' in excel, it turns in an 'xE9' in the xml-file.

I would be extreemly greatful I somebody could help me with this problem :)

Comment: `&#xE9;` is [a valid way](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references#Character_reference_overview) to represent `é` in an XML.

Comment: Hi GSerg, the problem is that the program that needs the XML-files gives an error at the lines where xE9 appear

Comment: Try `FileFormat:=xlUnicodeText`

Comment: Hi CDP1802, é is now shown correctly, but each line is placed between quotation marks ( " ) now. (this is slightly better because manually replacing " in each file is less work then pauzing the macro each time for a copy-paste

Comment: How much code is the complete script ? Is it possible to add it to your question ?

Comment: Hi CDP1802, That's not possible I'm afraid. It combines data from several sheets in a complex way, with a lot of loops and conditions. So it's a sht load of code. I've never exported something to xml, so I just populate a sheet with exact syntax and tabs, as it should appear in xml. The only problem with this method appear to be the accented characters. The number of xml-lines is between 50k and 300k

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```vb
Sub SaveUTF8()

   Const NameOfTheFile = "test"
   
   Dim FSO, ts, ar, strFilename As String, s As String
   Dim i As Long, t0 As Single: t0 = Timer

   strFilename = ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\" & NameOfTheFile & ".xml"

   Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
   Set ts = FSO.createTextfile(strFilename, 1, 1) ' oversrite, utf8
 
   ar = Sheets(1).UsedRange.Columns(1).Value2 'NameofSheetContainingData

   For i = LBound(ar) To UBound(ar)
       s = s & ar(i, 1) & vbCrLf
       If i Mod 1000 = 0 Then
           ts.write s
           s = ""
       End If
   Next
   ts.write s
   ts.Close
   MsgBox strFilename & " created in " & Int(Timer - t0) & " seconds"
   
End Sub
```

Alternative

```vb
Sub SaveUTF8_2()

    Const NameOfTheFile = "test"
   
    Dim strFilename As String, cell As Range
    Dim t0 As Single: t0 = Timer

    strFilename = ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\" & NameOfTheFile & ".xml"

    Dim objStream
    Set objStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
    With objStream
        .Type = 2 'adTypeText
        .Open
        .Charset = "UTF-8"
        For Each cell In Sheets(1).UsedRange.Columns(1).Cells
            .writetext cell.Value2, 1 'adWriteLine
        Next
        .Position = 0
        .SaveToFile strFilename, 2  'adSaveCreateOverWrit
    End With
    objStream.Close
    MsgBox strFilename & " created in " & Int(Timer - t0) & " seconds"

End Sub

Sub testdata()
    Sheet1.Range("A1:A300000").Value2 = _
    "<tag atr1=""attribute one"" atr2=""attribute two"">some text here ééé</tag>"
End Sub
```

update - batch write 1000 lines

update2 - added alternative

Comment: Thnx! Does what it has to do it appears! This takes about 1h for 40k lines, So for the whole macro this would boil down to 20h. Is there maybe a way to speed this up?

Comment: @nico It should take seconds !. How long did the saveas method take and how big (megabytes) was the file ?

Comment: The saveas is a few seconds. File size is about 2MB. I first made a sub myself that cycles the rows and writes 1 line at a time. But because it took a very long time for a small set, I searched the web and encoutered the saveas-method.

Comment: @nico I don't know why the writes are taking so long, is the workbook on a network drive ?. A 300k line file of 2MB is only a few bytes per line.  I have amended the code to write in batches of 1000 lines. Try that.

Comment: The file was indeed on a network drive. I moved it to the desktop and now it only takes a few seconds! Unfortunatly it appeared I opend the wrong test-file earlier. The accents still show up as xe9 :(. I think I'm going to replace them with plain letters as it only affects 1000lines.

Comment: @nico OK one more try, see update alternative.